# AnimeJS Progressive Fill of an SVG path

Tags: javascript, svg, anime.js

I have an SVG with different paths, and I want to animate the "fill" of these paths so it looks like it's being "hand drawn".

So far i Feel like I'm pretty close using the "strokeDashoffset" of anime.js, but I don't want the "borders" to be animated, I want the inside

Here's what I have :

JS :

```
  var cssSelector = anime({
    targets: '#cssSelector .lines path',
    strokeDashoffset: [anime.setDashoffset, 0],
    easing: 'easeInOutSine',
    duration: 1500,
    delay: function(el, i) { return i * 250 },
    direction: 'alternate',
    loop: false
  });
```

SVG/html

```
  <div id="cssSelector">
    <svg
       width="100%"
       height="auto"
       viewBox="0 0 122.84119 21.053778">
      <g
         transform="translate(-44.718109,-94.290359)">
        <g
           fill="#FFF" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="0.1" class="lines" stroke-linecap="round"
           id="text12">
          <path
             d="m 44.718109,95.475692 h 1.439333 v 19.755558 h -1.439333 z"
             style=""
             id="path14" />
          <path
             d="m 59.899459,114.29991 q -0.536222,0.508 -1.354666,0.79023 -0.790222,0.254 -1.665111,0.254 -1.919111,0 -2.963334,-1.04423 -1.044222,-1.07244 -1.044222,-2.96333 v -9.62378 h -2.709333 v -1.21355 h 2.709333 v -3.217336 h 1.411111 v 3.217336 h 4.684889 v 1.21355 h -4.684889 v 9.48267 q 0,1.43933 0.677334,2.20133 0.705555,0.73378 2.060222,0.73378 1.382889,0 2.286,-0.81844 z"
             style=""
             id="path16" />
          <path
             d="m 97.978291,95.475692 -6.688667,19.755558 h -1.524 L 83.641402,97.507692 77.488958,115.23125 h -1.524 L 69.24807,95.475692 h 1.523999 l 6.011334,17.779998 6.180666,-17.779998 h 1.382889 l 6.152444,17.808218 6.067778,-17.808218 z"
             style=""
             id="path18" />
          <path
             d="m 106.30297,115.34414 q -2.08845,0 -3.78178,-0.95956 -1.66511,-0.95956 -2.624668,-2.65289 -0.959556,-1.72155 -0.959556,-3.86644 0,-2.14489 0.959556,-3.83822 0.959558,-1.72156 2.624668,-2.68112 1.69333,-0.95955 3.78178,-0.95955 2.08844,0 3.75355,0.95955 1.69333,0.95956 2.65289,2.68112 0.95956,1.69333 0.95956,3.83822 0,2.14489 -0.95956,3.86644 -0.95956,1.69333 -2.65289,2.65289 -1.66511,0.95956 -3.75355,0.95956 z m 0,-1.27 q 1.69333,0 3.01977,-0.79023 1.35467,-0.79022 2.11667,-2.20133 0.79022,-1.41111 0.79022,-3.21733 0,-1.80622 -0.79022,-3.21734 -0.762,-1.41111 -2.11667,-2.20133 -1.32644,-0.79022 -3.01977,-0.79022 -1.69334,0 -3.048,0.79022 -1.32645,0.79022 -2.11667,2.20133 -0.762,1.41112 -0.762,3.21734 0,1.80622 0.762,3.21733 0.79022,1.41111 2.11667,2.20133 1.35466,0.79023 3.048,0.79023 z"
             style=""
             id="path20" />
          <path
             d="m 119.37382,103.71658 q 0.67733,-1.60867 2.11667,-2.45533 1.43933,-0.87489 3.49955,-0.87489 v 1.38289 l -0.33866,-0.0282 q -2.45534,0 -3.83823,1.55222 -1.38288,1.524 -1.38288,4.26155 v 7.67645 h -1.41112 v -14.732 h 1.35467 z"
             style=""
             id="path22" />
          <path
             d="m 134.12743,107.35725 -3.83822,3.49955 v 4.37445 h -1.41112 V 94.290359 h 1.41112 v 14.816661 l 9.42622,-8.60777 h 1.80622 l -6.35,5.95489 6.97089,8.77711 h -1.74978 z"
             style=""
             id="path24" />
          <path
             d="m 148.75404,115.34414 q -1.778,0 -3.38667,-0.53623 -1.60866,-0.53622 -2.51177,-1.35466 l 0.64911,-1.12889 q 0.90311,0.762 2.31422,1.27 1.43933,0.508 2.99155,0.508 2.22956,0 3.27378,-0.73378 1.07245,-0.73378 1.07245,-2.032 0,-0.93133 -0.59267,-1.46756 -0.56444,-0.53622 -1.41111,-0.79022 -0.84667,-0.254 -2.34245,-0.53622 -1.74977,-0.31044 -2.82222,-0.67733 -1.07244,-0.36689 -1.83444,-1.18534 -0.762,-0.81844 -0.762,-2.25777 0,-1.74978 1.43933,-2.87867 1.46756,-1.15711 4.14867,-1.15711 1.41111,0 2.794,0.39511 1.38289,0.39511 2.25778,1.04422 l -0.64912,1.12889 q -0.90311,-0.64911 -2.06022,-0.98778 -1.15711,-0.33866 -2.37066,-0.33866 -2.06023,0 -3.10445,0.762 -1.04422,0.762 -1.04422,2.00377 0,0.98778 0.59267,1.55223 0.59266,0.53622 1.43933,0.81844 0.87489,0.254 2.42711,0.56444 1.72156,0.31045 2.76578,0.67734 1.07244,0.33866 1.80622,1.12889 0.73378,0.79022 0.73378,2.17311 0,1.83444 -1.524,2.93511 -1.524,1.10067 -4.28978,1.10067 z"
             style=""
             id="path26" />
          <path
             d="m 165.55552,95.475692 h 1.63689 l -0.28222,14.082888 h -1.07245 z m 0.81845,19.868448 q -0.47978,0 -0.81845,-0.33867 -0.33866,-0.33867 -0.33866,-0.81845 0,-0.47977 0.33866,-0.81844 0.33867,-0.33867 0.81845,-0.33867 0.508,0 0.84666,0.33867 0.33867,0.33867 0.33867,0.81844 0,0.47978 -0.33867,0.81845 -0.33866,0.33867 -0.84666,0.33867 z"
             style=""
             id="path28" />
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
```

And here's the result (after the animation)

[image]

My first idea was to draw the stroke inside of the element with a big "stroke-width", but appearently there's nothing to do so.

Thanks for your help and sorry for bad english :)

Comment: Fills have no direction, you need to describe it in detail yourself. In case of these text-like shapes, you'll need to work your way along the aparent "writing". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49957299/animating-svg-fill-linearly-along-length-of-path/49958547#49958547 for a technique that might work for you.

Comment: I'll have a look at this. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is no way to do it with pure CSS. ended up following this tutorial and it worked Great

https://medium.com/@anatacreative/handwriting-animation-with-svg-638931410cfa